# What is the best way of auto generate swagger in Node.js, Express, Sequelize and PostgreSQL REST project?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to if there is any way to auto generate swagger for my REST project.

List of dependencies with version I use

- "Node_Version:"16.0.0",
- "express": "^4.18.2",
- "pg": "^8.11.1",
- "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
- "postgres": "^3.3.5",
- "sequelize": "^6.32.1"

Here are my Models

```
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import { sequelize } from '../services/database.js';

const User = sequelize.define('users', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    active: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: true
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
            isEmail: true
        }
    },
    fullName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    phone: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        validate: {
            len: {
                args: [10, 10],
                msg: 'Phone number can only be of length 10'
            }
        }
    },
    address: {
        type: DataTypes.JSONB,
        defaultValue: `{ streetAddress: '', state: '', zipCode: '', city: '' }`,
        get() {
            return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue('address'));
        },
        set(value) {
            return this.setDataValue('address', JSON.stringify(value));
        }
    },
    dateOfBirth: {
        type: DataTypes.DATEONLY
    }
});

export default User;
```